# Implementers of a Protocol with TypeVars in signatures can't use their own types instead

Tags: python, protocols, mypy, python-typing, type-variables

I'm trying to give users of my protocols a way to use whatever they want as types for keys and values of some arbitrary data structure.

Usually it will be a Dict, but it can easily be some external data storage like Redis.

I tried using Protocol to give this options to users, but mypy doesn't allow implementers to use their custom defined types in methods singnatures.

Is there a way to fix this typing or am I fundamentally using wrong tools here?

I'm using Python 3.11 and here's the script:

```py
from typing import (
    Dict,
    Generic,
    Optional,
    Protocol,
    Type,
    TypeVar,
    Union,
    runtime_checkable,
)

Key = TypeVar("Key")
Value = TypeVar("Value")


@runtime_checkable
class Data(Protocol):
    async def get_value(self, key: Key) -> Optional[Value]:
        ...

    async def set_value(self, key: Key, value: Value) -> None:
        ...


class DataUser(Generic[Key, Value]):
    def __init__(
        self,
        cls_data: Type[Data],
    ) -> None:
        self.__data = cls_data()

    async def get_value(self, key: Key) -> Optional[Value]:
        return await self.__data.get_value(key)

    async def set_value(self, key: Key, value: Value) -> None:
        await self.__data.set_value(key=key, value=value)


KVDataValue = Union[str, int, float]


class KVData:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.__data: Dict[str, KVDataValue] = {}

    async def get_value(self, key: str) -> Optional[KVDataValue]:
        return self.__data.get(key)

    async def set_value(self, key: str, value: KVDataValue) -> None:
        self.__data[key] = value


data_user = DataUser[str, KVDataValue](
    cls_data=KVData,
)
```

Running `mypy` on this code results in:

```py
src/aiomon/example.py:57:14: error: Argument "cls_data" to "DataUser" has incompatible type "Type[KVData]"; expected "Type[Data]"  [arg-type]
        cls_data=KVData,
                 ^~~~~~
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 11 source files)
```

Worth noting that I'm using PyCharm as my IDE and it shows that this is correct typing. Moreover when I, for example, remove `set_value` method from `KVData` it correctly identifies that this class stopped adhering to the `Data` Protocol.

Comment: I assume you are on Python `<=3.8` because you are using `typing.Dict` etc., but please mention your version explicitly in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the protocol is supposed to be generic in terms of what arguments its methods **accept** (and return), you should define it as such. (see ["Generic Protocols" in PEP 544](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/#generic-protocols))

After all, `DataUser` is already generic and (if I understand your use case correctly) its type parameters should be bound to those of the underlying `Data` class.

This seems to work just fine:

```py
from typing import Generic, Optional, Protocol, TypeVar, Union, runtime_checkable

K = TypeVar("K", contravariant=True)
V = TypeVar("V")


@runtime_checkable
class Data(Protocol[K, V]):
    async def get_value(self, key: K) -> Optional[V]: ...

    async def set_value(self, key: K, value: V) -> None: ...


class DataUser(Generic[K, V]):
    def __init__(self, cls_data: type[Data[K, V]]) -> None:
        self.__data = cls_data()

    async def get_value(self, key: K) -> Optional[V]:
        return await self.__data.get_value(key)

    async def set_value(self, key: K, value: V) -> None:
        await self.__data.set_value(key=key, value=value)


KVDataValue = Union[str, int, float]


class KVData:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.__data: dict[str, KVDataValue] = {}

    async def get_value(self, key: str) -> Optional[KVDataValue]:
        return self.__data.get(key)

    async def set_value(self, key: str, value: KVDataValue) -> None:
        self.__data[key] = value


data_user = DataUser[str, KVDataValue](cls_data=KVData)
```

Passes `mypy --strict` without errors.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, the `[K, V]` was missing in `Protocol[K, V]`.